# Rolling upgrade/deployment for wine?

Tags: upgrade, wine, lubuntu, deployment, rolling-release

While I am using wine to run some Windows exe program files on Lubuntu 18.04, I update and upgrade which probably have updated wine.

While I am still running the Windows exe programs,  I try to run another Windows exe program,

```
$ wine another.exe
wine client error:0: version mismatch 547/571.
Your wineserver binary was not upgraded correctly,
or you have an older one somewhere in your PATH.
Or maybe the wrong wineserver is still running?
```

I don't want to exit the running Windows exe programs. Does that mean I shouldn't kill the running wine processes? 
What can I do to start the other window exe program?

Is this a common problem in deployment: rolling upgrade/deployment?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done to address the error diagnostic?

Comment: `cp -r ~/.wine ~/.wine-new`, `export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-new `and `wine winecfg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it’s too late for that, but the general rule is that you shouldn’t upgrade Wine when it’s running, or if you do, plan on restarting the running instances as soon as possible after upgrading. (This is true of a number of other programs, such as Firefox and LibreOffice.)

> I don't want to exit the running Windows exe programs. Does that mean I shouldn't kill the running wine processes?

Yes, you shouldn’t kill the running Wine processes.

> What can I do to start the other window exe program?

You *could* copy your current Wine prefix to a new one, and start the upgraded Wine there — Wine runs one server per prefix. Assuming your current Wine prefix is `~/.wine`, you would run

```
cp -a ~/.wine ~/.wine.new
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine.new wine /path/to/your/program.exe
```

> Is this a common problem in deployment: rolling upgrade/deployment?

Yes, or at least, it’s a scenario which needs to be explicitly addressed: new versions of the server need to accept and handle connections from older versions of the client. In Wine’s case, clients expect to connect to a server running the same version; there is no provision for split upgrades. This expectation is embedded in a number of places: the main `NTDLL` checks the `wineserver` version, a number of DLLs check their corresponding Wine driver version, etc.

Comment: Thanks. After copying prefix and renaming the copy directory, e.g. to `~/.wine-new`, is what remains to do exactly`export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-new` and `wine winecfg`? (https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_store_the_virtual_Windows_installation_somewhere_other_than_.7E.2F.wine.3F). In production of software engineering, how is rolling done broadly speaking?

Comment: I read https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-a-rolling-upgrade-in-software-development. Rolling upgrade seems to apply only to client-server software. Upgrade server while client of older version is still running. Does this require multiple instances of server and move request to other instance? Does this require the server of new version be compatible with client of old version? (In case of Wine, that is not true?) Does  client still need to be upgraded, but can be upgraded only after it voluntarily exit, or not necessarily since the server of new version can work with client of old version?

Comment: I think I get the idea. I will read more when I have time to.

Comment: By split upgrades, do you mean the software itself allows client and server with different versions to run together? Is that different from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release?

Comment: I’ve expanded my answer a little to address your prefix questions, and explain how software can handle rolling upgrades. Rolling upgrades are indeed only a problem when two pieces of software can be upgraded separately, but need to work together (and surprising though it may be, Wine is client-server software). Rolling *releases* are another matter entirely, releasing and upgrading are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: thanks. " it’s a scenario which needs to be explicitly addressed: new versions of the server need to accept and handle connections from older versions of the client."  In wine case, is it that new version of client can't work with running old version of server? Is it reasonable to require a server to work with newer version of client?

Comment: If a software application is single process, when upgrade its version while it is running, is it correct that we never have to worry about its down time, because its older version is running as a process in memory, without being affected by the deployed new version replacement?